# C# Enumerations in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to store multiple enumerations [C#] and its friendly names  in ONE database table.

Is there a standard naming convention for such table?

Is OTLT is right term? Does anyone used such table in your project?

Please refer : 
[enums in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792566/enums-in-sql-server-database?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Could you add some examples (to your question) of what you want to store (C# code) and how you want it stored (sql)?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470361/anti-the-anti-pattern-otlt-in-postgres-using-inheritance

Comment: Are doing it in EF or EF core code first? It will be enough if you define enum in c# code and declare fields in your entity class. E.g. public MyEnumType?  enumeration;

Comment: You've encountered the term OTLT, you've presumably searched on that, and yet you still think it's a *good* idea?

Comment: To answer your question - no. Refer to [one table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approch-good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@derin we use `enumlookup` table  on our project which is comprise such columns as namespace, enumcode, displayname.

This table is using only when we decide that we need to work with specific set of enum values which can be extended/reduced in future

we have an according EnumLookupManager which is helping us to manage these enums